# Nodemcu bootloader incompatible with ESP32-C3?

Tags: esp32, nodemcu

I thought that the WeMos LOLIN Mini ESP32-C3 looked like a great board - same footprint as a D1 Mini; fast; sensible price; good availability.  I purchased a few.

However flashing with Nodemcu failed, and I discovered that the ESP32-C3 starts its bootloader at 0x0000, not the 0x1000 address used by (all?) other ESP32 devices.

"make menuconfig" does have a bootloader submenu, but that doesn't have a "start address" option.

I *think* the Bootloader start offset is defined by BOOTLOADER_OFFSET in 'Makefile.projbuild' in '~/sdk/esp32-esp-idf/components/bootloader/' but have no idea if there are any absolute jumps in or out of the bootloader, or anything else that will be messed up by just changing this.

So - has anybody been down this rabbithole before?  Am I on the right track or is unrealistic to expect to run Nodemcu on an ESP32-C3?

Thanks

Comment: it is not supported

Comment: Understood; I was thinking about doing it myself, unsupported. But the very helpful clarification from X Zhang has convinced me that would be a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Original NodeMCU were designed to run on Xtensa cores (ESP8266/ESP12), and ESP32-C3 runs a RISC-V core, it's like apples and pears, from the same farm. No, they are not inherently interchangeable. It's not impossible to create a compatible eco-system around these two species, but a lot of extra efforts are expected.

Comment: Aha - so, a different compiler target, most likely followed by a vast amount of JTAG debugging, for... no material benefit, really.  I think this goes in the "don't even think about it" category.

Comment: Donno, everything works on, e.g. Arduino IDE, to a certain extent, so some of the necessary tips and tricks are already there. But I share your feeling on the 'benefit' side of things, maybe we should keep nagging the board or MCU vendors for a supported toolchain.